# How do you mute from the command line?

Tags: command-line, pulseaudio, alsa

How do you mute the sound system from the command line?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Assuming you're using ALSA driver, run:

```
amixer set Master mute   
amixer set Master unmute
```

Or, you can just use:

```
amixer set Master toggle
```

to toggle mute on and off.

Comment: for me / my system (precise), this only goes one way: off / mute. Neither toggle nor unmute bring the music back on. Any ideas as to why??

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/77522/command-to-unmute-and-maximize-volume

Comment: This solution is for pure Alsa. For Alsa with pulseaudio, use the command from [Tim's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/444183). Or don't touch the command and instead configure Alsa as in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/517453). Else, @nutty about natty's problem of not being able to unmute results.

Comment: on Ubuntu Server 14.04 "Master" was not available as a simple control. I used "Speaker" in its place. I found the substitution by running `sudo amixer` and finding the line in the output that matched `Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0`

Answer (score 64):

This worked for me when others didn't:

```
amixer -q -D pulse sset Master toggle
```

This is from the link in [nutty about natty's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77522/command-to-unmute-and-maximize-volume) to the first answer:

Comment: I also just checked, it works on 14.04 too.

Comment: did it :) - kubuntu here (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS). thx.

Comment: This `-D pulse` option is needed when Alsa is used with pulseaudio (and since the question is tagged pulseaudio, this should be the accepted answer). For more details about this solution, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/544754) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/118675) on askubuntu.

Comment: Note: The accepted answer by @goric doesn't work when headphones or earphones are plugged in, use this.

Comment: Or, less ambiguously than "toggle", you can use `amixer -q -D pulse sset Master mute` and 
`amixer -q -D pulse sset Master unmute`.  Works great on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @CPBL sure, that didn't work for me when I answered this

Comment: this also worked for me to mute  the bluetooth speaker, which was not affected by the default laptop button

Answer (score 54):

I'm using **`pactl`** in my scripts. From [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/pactl.1.html#commands):

> `set-sink-mute SINK 1|0|toggle`: Set the mute status of the specified sink (identified by its symbolic name or numerical index)

To mute:

```
pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ true
```

To unmute:

```
pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ false
```

To toggle:

```
pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle
```

Use `0` instead of `@DEFAULT_SINK@` to set the sink with numerical index 0. true=="1", false=="0".

Tested on Ubuntu 12.10.
In my setup sometimes amixer unmute fails for some reason.

Comment: Still works in Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: LIkely, this is the proper way to perform the operation on modern Ubuntu versions. Works on 16.04 (amixer doesn't).

Comment: You can also toggle from mute to unmute and back: `pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle`

Comment: Sink 0 might not be the relevant one. For me, 0 was the monitor's output and 1 the laptop speakers, so I needed to do `pactl set-sink-mute 1 0` to unmute them.

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 17):

On the terminal type this to mute

```
amixer set Master mute
```

type

```
amixer set Master unmute
```

Tested on my Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `alsa` follow goric answer.

PulseAudio is better, but not so simple: `pactl set-sink-mute 0 1` Do the work for the first device, but not if you are using headphones of another sink output.

The better way is to check with `pactl info` and get the `Default Sink` to use.

```
DEFAULT_SINK=$(pactl info | grep "Default Sink" | cut -d " " -f3)
```

Then to mute:

```
pactl set-sink-mute "$DEFAULT_SINK" "1"
```

Or unmute:

```
pactl set-sink-mute "$DEFAULT_SINK" "0"
```

I wrote a script to manage pulseaudio in my note. If you want to use, save it as `volume`, provide execute permissions `chmod +x volume` and add it to your path `ln -sv $PWD/volume /usr/local/bin/`. Here my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# script name: volume
# Author: glaudistong at gmail.com
# depends on: yad, coreutils, pulseaudio

ps -ef | grep "yad" | grep -E "Volume [^+\-]" | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f2 | xargs -i kill "{}" 2>/dev/null
DEFAULT_SINK=$(pactl info | grep "Default Sink" | cut -d " " -f3)
DEFAULT_SOURCE=$(pactl info | grep "Default Source" | cut -d " " -f3)
case "$1" in 
    init)
    {
        ps -fe | grep yad | grep -q volume ||
        {
         yad --notification --command "volume up" --text "+ Volume +" --image ~/Pictures/volume-up-dark.png &
         yad --notification --command "volume down" --text "- Volume -" --image ~/Pictures/volume-down-dark.png &
        }
    };;
    up)
    {
        pactl set-sink-volume "$DEFAULT_SINK" +5%
        P=$(pactl list | grep -E "Name: $DEFAULT_SINK$|Volume" | grep "Name:" -A1 | tail -1 | cut -d% -f1 | cut -d/ -f2 | tr -d " ")
        iconl="$(echo -ne "\U1F50A")"
        iconr="$(echo -ne "\U1F56A")"
        timeout .6 yad --progress --percentage "$P" --timeout 1 --no-buttons --undecorated --text="$iconl Volume $P% $iconr" --no-focus --center --skip-taskbar --on-top &
    };;
    down)
    {
        pactl set-sink-volume "$DEFAULT_SINK" -5%
        P=$(pactl list | grep -E "Name: $DEFAULT_SINK$|Volume" | grep "Name:" -A1 | tail -1 | cut -d% -f1 | cut -d/ -f2 | tr -d " ")
        iconl="$(echo -ne "\U1F509")"
        iconr="$(echo -ne "\U1F569")"
        timeout .6 yad --progress --percentage "$P" --timeout 1 --no-buttons --undecorated --text="$iconl Volume $P% $iconr" --no-focus --center --skip-taskbar --on-top &
    };;
    mute)
    {
        ismute=$(pactl list | grep -E "Name: $DEFAULT_SINK$|Mute" | grep "Name:" -A1 | tail -1 |cut -d: -f2| tr -d " ")
        if [ "$ismute" == no ]; then
            s=1
            P=0
            icon="$(echo -ne "\U1F507")"
        else
            P=$(pactl list | grep -E "Name: $DEFAULT_SINK$|Volume" | grep "Name:" -A1 | tail -1 | cut -d% -f1 | cut -d/ -f2 | tr -d " ")
            icon=""
            s=0
        fi
        pactl set-sink-mute "$DEFAULT_SINK" "$s"
        echo $s > /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/platform::mute/brightness
        timeout .6 yad --progress --percentage "$P" --timeout 1 --no-buttons --undecorated --text="$icon Volume $P%" --no-focus --center --skip-taskbar --on-top &
    };;
    mic-up)
    {
        pactl set-source-volume "$DEFAULT_SOURCE" +5%
        P=$(pactl list | grep -E "Name: $DEFAULT_SOURCE$|Volume" | grep "Name:" -A1 | tail -1 | cut -d% -f1 | cut -d/ -f2 | tr -d " ")
        icon="$(echo -en "\U1F3A4")"
        timeout .6 yad --progress --percentage "$P" --timeout 1 --no-buttons --undecorated --text="$icon Volume Mic $P%" --no-focus --center --skip-taskbar --on-top &
    };;
    mic-down)
    {
        pactl set-source-volume "$DEFAULT_SOURCE" -5%
        icon="$(echo -en "\U1F3A4")"
        P=$(pactl list | grep -E "Name: $DEFAULT_SOURCE$|Volume" | grep "Name:" -A1 | tail -1 | cut -d% -f1 | cut -d/ -f2 | tr -d " ")
        timeout .6 yad --progress --percentage "$P" --timeout 1 --no-buttons --undecorated --text="$icon Volume Mic $P%" --no-focus --center --skip-taskbar --on-top &
    };;
    mic-mute)
    {
        ismute=$(pactl list | grep -E "Name: $DEFAULT_SOURCE$|Mute" | grep "Name:" -A1 | tail -1 |cut -d: -f2| tr -d " ")
        if [ "$ismute" == no ]; then
            s=1
            P=0
            icon="$(echo -en "\U1F507\U1F3A4")"
        else
            P=$(pactl list | grep -E "Name: $DEFAULT_SOURCE$|Volume" | grep "Name:" -A1 | tail -1 | cut -d% -f1 | cut -d/ -f2 | tr -d " ")
            s=0
            icon="$(echo -en "\U1F3A4")"
        fi
        pactl set-source-mute "$DEFAULT_SOURCE" "$s"
        echo $s > /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/platform::micmute/brightness
        timeout .6 yad --progress --percentage "$P" --timeout 1 --no-buttons --undecorated --text="$icon Volume Mic $P%" --no-focus --center --skip-taskbar --on-top &
    };;
    *)
        echo invalid option;;
esac;
```

Comment: As a minor improvement, you can reference the default sink/source with a value of `@DEFAULT_SINK@` and `@DEFAULT_SOURCE@` respectively, instead of grepping the output of a query.

Answer (score 2):

if your are using pulseaudio as the sound server then do this

```sh
pactl -- set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle # Also true/false to mute/unmute
```

to mute and unmute

if using alsa then use this

```
amixer sset 'Master' toggle
```

to mute and unmute