# Lubuntu 14.04: unmute sound from keyboard not work

Tags: 14.04, sound, lubuntu

When i press mute button on keyboard, it works. But when i press it second times, sound not unmute. How to repair it ?

This key on xubuntu 14.04 works good.
Hardware is samsung 550p5c.

Comment: Solved. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001690

Comment: Can you please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) with whatever on that thread worked for you?

Comment: All infos from that thread are now in @Hrvoje's answer. Except how to also make unmuting work by pressing the VolUp / VolDown keys (as they are intended to).

Answer (score 9):

I also had the same problem. Author has provided a link in the comments with a forum post where it has been solved, but for completeness, if somebody else runs into this post, here is a solution.

The problem with unmuting is that pressing the button unmutes only the master channel but not Pulsaudio channels. To correct this one has to modify the keybinding for `XF86AudioMute` button which on Lubuntu is defined in file `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`. Open the file with a text editor and find `<keybind key="XF86AudioMute">`, and in `<command>` section put the following command: `amixer -D pulse set Master Playback Switch toggle`.

This question has been discussed at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118675/mute-key-mutes-alsa-and-pulseaudio-but-unmutes-only-alsa) as well, but that one is actually difficult to find if you do not know that Alsa is the problem, which can easily happen to an Ubuntu newbie.

At the end run `openbox --reconfigure` to set the configuration.

Comment: After changing the `lubuntu-rc.xml` file, of course make OpenBox read its new configuration to let the changes take effect. Just execute `openbox --reconfigure`, no restart required. [[source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/openbox#Openbox_reconfiguration)]

Comment: And according to [this new comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/118675/mute-key-mutes-alsa-and-pulseaudio-but-unmutes-only-alsa#comment855265_352322) over at the other askubuntu discussion, technically the correct command is `amixer -D pulse set Master toggle`. The one you have also works though.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to make the speaker or headphone state follow the state of the master channel depending on if you have the headphones plugged in or not. This script does it for me on my ancient Dell Latitude laptop:

```
#!/bin/bash

amixer -q sset Master toggle

MASTER_STATE=`amixer get Master | awk -F"dB] " 'NR == 5 {print $2;}'`
HEADPHONES_PLUGGED=`amixer contents | grep -A 2 Headphone\ Jack | awk -F"=" 'NR == 3 {print $2;}'`

if [[ $HEADPHONES_PLUGGED == 'on' ]]; then
    SLAVE="Headphone"
else
    SLAVE="Speaker+LO"
fi

if [[ $MASTER_STATE == '[on]' ]]; then
    amixer -q sset $SLAVE unmute
else
    amixer -q sset $SLAVE mute
fi
```

You may need to check your channels with amixer on your computer and change the SLAVE definitions accordingly. Also the "Headphone\ Jack" grep string in the HEADPHONES_PLUGGED definition might need to be something else.

To hook into the toggle button you should make the above script available through your `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` configuration file.

```
<keybind key="XF86AudioMute">
    <action name="Execute">
        <!--command>amixer -q sset Master toggle</command-->
        <command>/usr/local/bin/amixer-toggle.sh</command>
    </action>
</keybind>
```