# Manage Keyboard Shortcuts in Ubuntu with LXDE

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, lxde

My problem is that after I switched from GNOME to LXDE I can't use my keyboard shortcuts for volume correctly (I can't unmute). Whenever I change the commands in `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` nothing changes. What could be the reason?

Comment: A lot of questions I found (for example this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/544754/lubuntu-14-04-unmute-sound-from-keyboard-not-work). Yes I tried reconfigure and logout and restart, nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Indeed I needed to work on the lxde-rc file not the lubuntu one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the login screen you can choose your session, and `openbox` uses different `.xml` files for the different sessions:

- for **Lubuntu** sessions:

  ```
  ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
  ```
- for **LXDE** sessions:

  ```
  ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
  ```
- for **Openbox** sessions:

  ```
  ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml
  ```

After editing the correct file either execute `openbox --reconfigure` or  log out and log in again to apply the changes.