# Display Settings popup makes it impossible to use LXDE in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, lxde

I used the below command to install LXDE in default 18.04

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

I got in through login session to LXDE. It was working fine then " Display Settings " window with monitor details keep popping up. No matter what I do, it annoyingly comes back. If I leave it untouched, around 10-15 windows will be there in a minute. Is there a way to fix this ? Thanks

[image]

Just noticed : The windows got added as a pack of two at a time.

Comment: I had a similar issue on my previous laptop. It was a DELL Inspiron N5110. I didn't find a solution, but a workaround. The workaround was disabling `xrandr` from `dconf`. You may try it by running `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr active false`.

Comment: I tried that @user3140225 , but it came back :(

Comment: I just remembered that I used to do one more thing: disable `XF86Display` key (the key that you press to open display settings). I had found the keycode of it using `xev` and then I used `xmodmap` to disable it. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54417/how-to-disable-keys-from-the-keyboard) for how to disable a key with `xmodmap`. Also, is there a chance that you've spilt any liquid on your keyboard?

Comment: Everything works fine in default Gnome Ubuntu. I wanted to be light on resources hence installed LXDE. Thanks.

Comment: I see. This issue appears [on XFCE too](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6828). There is another workaround in this link. It may be worth trying. As a final thought, try to disable the display setting shortcut, which is probably set to XF86Display and perhaps to Super+P and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you. Where can  I disable that shortcut in LXDE ?

Comment: You have to edit one of the files [mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978201/manage-keyboard-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-with-lxde), depending on the session you use. Open the file with your text editor,  search for the shortcuts and comment out their entries. Combine this with my suggestions on the previous comments.

Comment: Thank you. I am finding hard to follow. Will installing `lubuntu-desktop` fix this bug ?

Comment: I doubt it, but you never know.