# How do I automatically mute/unmute sound during a certain time period (e.g. night)?

Tags: software-recommendation, mute

Is there an app to mute the computer say 10PM to 7:30AM? (On Android devices I use: [phone silencer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.ebak.phone_silencer&hl=en) )

Comment: We do that from command line. See this duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26068/how-do-you-mute-from-the-command-line All you need to do is toss the command in /etc/crontab with a time stamp.

Comment: I don't think that's a close enough dupe. OP needs help scripting this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the link in the comments of @Rinzwind: [How do you mute from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26068/how-do-you-mute-from-the-command-line)

Use crontab to mute and unmute the computer at night as follows:

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter **one of the** the following lines to edit the `/etc/cron.d` file:

**For a regular user, use the following command:**

```
crontab -e
```

**For system-wide solution, use the following command:**

```
sudo crontab -e
```

At the end of the resulting file add the following two lines:

```
00 22 * * * amixer set Master mute
29 07 * * * amixer set Master unmute
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd> to save and exit `crontab`.

**Explanations:**

Each line in `crontab` has five time-and-date fields, followed by a command, followed by a newline character ('\n'). The fields are separated by spaces. The five time-and-date fields cannot contain spaces. The five time-and-date fields are as follows:

1. minute (0-59),
2. hour (0-23, 0 = midnight),
3. day (1-31),
4. month (1-12),
5. weekday (0-6, 0 = Sunday).

See the [CronHowto in Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) for more details.

**Note: This will not work if the machine is off at the predefined time.** For example, if power goes off at 9PM and comes back at 11PM, audio will not be muted when the power comes back.

Hope this helps

Comment: Is this sufficient? What if I power down my machine at 9pm and power it back up at 11pm? The cronjob will not be run.

Comment: @noffle No, regular cron will not run missed tasks because of downtime. You might want to look into [anacron](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/tag/anacron-ubuntu/) in order to have this to be more targeted for desktop usage.

Comment: @user68186 Looks good, thanks for applying this. I've removed my comment now.

Comment: @TomBrossman, Thanks! I had help from the comments by Rinzwind and gertvdijk.

Comment: @user68186 Is there a way to mute the sound from HDMI? The above code only mutes the sound from speakers. prntscr.com/exx8mc

Comment: @user251223 I don't know. I don't have HDMI connected sound.