# Problem with sound volume with xfce on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: xfce, volume-control

I find that when I mute or set the volume to zero using the mixer control in the top xfce4-panel, I cannot raise the volume again.  It remains silent until I sign out and sign back in again using the default Ubuntu desktop (Unity, I believe).  In the default desktop, I'll see that the volume is muted, and so I raise the volume here.  Then it works here and when I sign back into my xfce4 desktop.  It will keep working unless I mute it once again, at which point I have to go through the same steps that I've described.  I try both the xfce4-mixer and alsa-mixer, but this does not work.  The only thing that works is signing out and signing back in to the default desktop, which is tedious to do.

Comment: sounds like a bug - this may help (http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2122906.html) - if it does, please post an answer and say exactly which bits worked for you.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I did sorta solve this.  I installed gnome-alsa-mixer and with this I was unable to unmute the volume.  Seems that the "headphone", "PCM", and "Speaker" were set to mute.  When I tried to unmute these with the xfce4-mixer, it refused to unmute all three together, but I was able to do this with the gnome-alsa-mixer from within the xfce4 desktop.  Odd, but at least I didn't have to sign out into a different desktop to do it.  PS, thanks for your response fossfreedom.  I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was on mute and I solved the issue doing this:

1. open terminal
2. type `amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+`
3. keep doing it until Left and right are at 100%

Alternatively, do this:

1. open terminal
2. type `amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the xfce sound mixer doesn't work well with pulseaudio. I have found the following two commands helpfull.

run the following command to turn mute on:

```
pactl set-sink-mute 0 1
```

run the following command to turn mute off:

```
pactl set-sink-mute 0 0
```

https://askubuntu.com/a/404242/167115

Answer (score 0):

I have each of these commands set to keyboard shortcuts. It may or may not solve this bug though.

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle
```

The last one toggles between muted and not muted.