# Turn off error sound on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system, settings, 18.04, gsettings

How do I turn off the Ubuntu error sound (especially on the terminal) in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Try this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/26068/how-do-you-mute-from-the-command-line

Comment: Got to `System-settings->Sound->Sound Effects->Alert volume` and turn the switch to OFF.

Comment: Try this [Turn off Motherboard/PC Speaker “beep” in Ubuntu 16.04 regression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829258/turn-off-motherboard-pc-speaker-beep-in-ubuntu-16-04-regression)

Comment: I have a related problem: I can't stand Ubuntu 18's terminal bell, but following this advice, I realize the sound has two components: a) the one selected in "Sound Effect", and, b) a deep, practically booming reverb of the selection.  I want to keep the first sound, but kill the reverb.  Not only is it jarring, but in the lab where I work it is annoying to others, because it really carries.  (Should I make this it's own question?)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In order to turn off Ubuntu error sound in Ubuntu 18.04 you need to go 
*Setting > Sound > Sound Effects > Alert Volume > Off*.

[image: Sound settings dialogue]

Comment: it is good to know there is even bark..

Comment: This alert control seems to not exist on Ubuntu 19.10. The solution given by [Nick Hope](https://askubuntu.com/a/1091357/1035404) does work, though

Comment: YES! This option mutes all of the alert sounds I constantly have whenever I'm holding down `Backspace` to remove a few characters in the text input field. Finally, no more constant alert sound effects in my headphones.

Comment: @dgallant You have obviously never used Puppy Linux

Comment: Ubuntu 20 has removed this option :| This is really annoying in the text editor.

Comment: @aderchox check Nick's answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1091357/757695

Answer (score 64):

If you just want to turn off on terminal in Ubuntu 18.04, open *Terminal* > *Edit* > *Preference*
then choose your terminal profile and uncheck *Terminal Bell*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this should have been the accepted solution!

Answer (score 38):

Add the following line to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
bind 'set bell-style none'
```

New terminals will have no error sound.

Comment: How about "~/.zshrc"? Doesn't work there.

Comment: @aderchox you can add this to your .zshrc 
`unsetopt BEEP`
from: https://blog.vghaisas.com/zsh-beep-sound/

Answer (score 14):

For turn off terminal sound you need go to terminal, then go to tab edit > preferences and uncheck terminal bell.

Answer (score 3):

Run this command in the terminal:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/event-sounds "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either edit /etc/inputrc (system wide) or ~/.inputrc

and add the line:

```
set bell-style none
```

(it might just be commented out)