# Ubuntu 19.04 - Turn off volume change sound

Tags: sound, volume-control

Every time I change volume I hear "beep" noise. How can I remove this ?
[image]

There is no way to remove "Alert Sound" in the settings. I am forced to select any of the 4 choices. I'm not sure whether alert sound has anything to do with my problem. Accepted answer of [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030515/turn-off-error-sound-on-ubuntu-18-04) question couldn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

the alert sound for volume change is located in `/usr/share/sounds/Yaru/stereo` if your sound theme is Yaru

[image]

So renaming or removing the file in the system sound theme directory, for example: `/usr/share/sounds/Yaru/stereo` with the file name `audio-volume-change.oga` will mute the alerts in every volume change..