# watch --beep doesn't work

Tags: command-line, manpage

I read `watch` command's manual page, found `-b` or `--beep`:

> -b, --beep
>
> Beep if command has a non-zero exit.

So I did:

```
$ watch --beep ls /root
```

Using a non-root account and it doesn't make a sound like a beep. How should I use this command?

Comment: Do you have [`beep`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/beep) installed? `sudo apt install beep` – Are you speakers unmuted?

Comment: Do you know if you have an internal pc speaker connected to your mother board?

Comment: @dessert I installed it some minutes ago, but it still doesn't work. My speakers are OK.

Comment: @SamuelSantana How to find that? I have a laptop, and I think my speakers are connected to the motherboard directly.

Comment: Check the asnwers for this question https://superuser.com/q/22767/701345 and perhaps specially this one https://superuser.com/a/44865/701345

Comment: Do you have the alert sound set on and loud enough, see here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1053142/507051

Comment: Is the `pcspkr` kernel module loaded? Do that with `sudo modprobe -v pcspkr` and try again.

Comment: If this still didn’t help please check your BIOS for settings for your internal speakers, especially for one to disable them.

Comment: Thanks to your all solutions. I found that in `alsamixer`, I have to enable the `loopback` device to enable beeping, but when I enable it, my laptop starts a kind of strange noise like a radio. How can I disable that noise without disabling the `loopback` device? @dessert

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments. It’s not a problem at all if your question changes because you gained knowledge, just edit and keep it up to date.