# How do you mute the output audio stream when it's silent automatically?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I have a pair of bluetooth headphones which have a 'standby' mode, in which they drop into a low-power state when the computer they are connected it isn't sending them an audio stream.

I can tell if they are in this low-power state because they make a very quiet buzzing sound when there's no sound playing, and this noise stops when they go into standby.

Unfortunately, with Ubuntu, they aren't dropping into this low-power state at all, at least until I manually restart pulseaudio with `pulseaudio --kill; pulseaudio --start` and then manually reconnect to the headphones through the bluetooth menu.

Sometimes I'll have to run the above several times in a day.

My question is this: How can I configure Ubuntu to cut the audio stream going to my bluetooth headphones when it's silent (even if an application is technically playing 'audio')?

I think I'm after a noise gate, but for the output stream rather than the input stream.

**Edit:** This is still an issue on both 20.04 and 20.10.

- Requested output from `journalctl -p warning | grep pulseaudio`: https://pastebin.com/9dsGhbBk
- I've tried muting completely as per https://askubuntu.com/a/404242/349837 - but it didn't help.
- The headphones in question are connected via Bluetooth, and are Philips SHB 7000 if it makes any difference.

Comment: This still happen to you on 20.04? Add the Brand+Model of the BT headphones. Check `journalctl -p warning | grep pulseaudio`. Did you try [muting completeley](https://askubuntu.com/a/404242/349837)?

Comment: Added details to the end of the question @PabloBianchi. In short: yes, this in still an issue.